# Registration form Bootstrap PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem with my form.
I want to create a registration form using an email and password.
But it is not inserting on my database.

I include the database connection correctly but I don't know why it s not inserting.

This is my PHP for the registration

```
<?php

 include ("dbconnection.php");

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 //gather all the data from the submission process

 $email        = $_POST['email'];
 $password   = $_POST['password'];

 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
 $date_created = date('D, d M o h:i:s O', time());

 $password = md5($password);

 $check_email = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tbl_clients WHERE email = '$email'") ;
 $checked_email = mysql_num_rows($check_email);

 if($checked_email != 0) {

  echo"<script>alert('Sorry that email is already taken')</script>";

 }

 else {

 $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_registration (email,
                                         password,
                         created) VALUE
                         ('".$email."',
                     '".$password."',
                         ".$date_created.")";

 $result = mysql_query($query);
  echo"<script>alert('Thank you for registering. Your registration is successful!')  
 </script>";
 }
 }
 ?>
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-push-1 col-md-5 col-md-push-1 col-sm-7 col-sm-push-1 col-xs-   
12">
<h3><b>Register</b></h3>

 <form role="form" method="post" action="">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="email">Email</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" 
  placeholder="Password">
 </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, please use something other than `MD5` LOL, like `sha256`

Comment: Thank you for you recommendations :)

Comment: `MD5` would be considered okay, as long as its salted and hashed. Same with `sha256` and any other encryption. @EliteGamer

Answer (score 1):

You need to write VALUES not VALUE

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_registration (email,
                                         password,
                         created) VALUES
                         ('".$email."',
                     '".$password."',
                         ".$date_created.")";
```

And BTW, i recommending to you to salt the password

Comment: I updated it but nothing happen. But thank you btw, I forgot to put "S"